# In Quarto, is there a way to include the searchbox on the index page

Tags: quarto

I would like to add a search input box to the index page of my Quarto site that utilizes the native search functionality. Ideally, I want it to look similar to Google's search bar. Is it possible to reuse the `Search.json` in Quarto for this purpose? I couldn't find any documentation on it aside from how to show/hide and display results for the nav bar search.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you please share some code you have tried?